# Tactics for fighting enemies in Iram of the Pillars

Tags: uncharted-3

Are there any good tactics for fighting the "fire" enemies in Iram of the Pillars? I'm having a lot of trouble with them, particularly in the first fight after you get drugged.

Comment: +1 these guys really annoyed me on Hard, not looking forward to this bit on Crushing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few "heavy" weapons scattered about in these areas that will make the fights easier. After the area with the elevator, there is a RPG you can grab near the cover directly in front of you.

In the last area that's quite large, it can be challenging to avoid being killed over and over as you aren't afforded much cover initially. However, there is a RPG on the left side that you can quickly run to which will help you dispatch some enemies, as well as a M32-Hammer right in front of the door that will open after you clear this area.

Comment: Indeed I found using heavy weapons worked out the best, shoot + run + shoot. Try to keep some distance as they 'teleport' themselves rather annoyingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found it reasonably easy to kill them using the sniper rifle or scoped pistol (Tau Sniper). It only takes 1-2 hits to kill them. If you can take them out quickly and keep some space between yourself and them, then in most cases you only have to deal with 1-2 at a time and they won't get a chance to damage you.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 'fire demons' themselves ..

- They each appear to need to be killed twice; a single direct hit with the RPG is enough for most enemies, but do this to a 'fire demon' and he explodes into a cloud of smoke and re-forms somewhere else. The thing is, if you pay attention to the smoke, it indicates which direction he will re-appear in. Before noticing this it seemed like they were just everywhere, but after seeing how the smoke predicts their moves, tracking their positions became a heck of a lot easier, making it much easier to out maneuver them.
- Their other weakness seems to be that they aren't very quick on the trigger (At least not on Hard anyway - Dunno about Crushing .. yet). If you keep moving and keep enough distance, it seems possible to get from place to place w/o too much trouble, so you can get weapon reloads etc.

Regarding particular fights ..

- In the first fight with them, there is a balcony in one corner of the map that isn't a bad place to hang out, since they can't flank you, but the down side is that while they may all be in front of you somewhere, they have lots of cover. Patience and good aim will see you through.
- In fight that follows the weird reflecting pool, however, the most important thing with these guys is to keep moving. More than a moment or two in cover and they will flank you. They have a tendency to come after you, so if you've drawn them to one side of the map, a quick sprint toward the other side can buy you enough time to turn and pick one off.

Comment: Having only just unlocked crushing, just got to these guys on that difficulty. Seems they can take *two* hits from a Big Gun before bursting into smoke & teleporting, on crushing. Still, not as tough as those (expletive!) blue guys from Uncharted 2.